# Determine if the date is today or is in the past using MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Im building a mini calendar that just displays the current month, I have figured out how to map out the calendar, here is the code:

**Code:**

```
var month  = moment(),
    index  = 0,
    maxDay = month.daysInMonth(),
    start  = month.startOf("month"),
    offset = (start.isoWeekday() - 1 + 7) % 7; // start from monday

var week = []; // holds the weeks
var days = []; // holds the days

do {

  var dayIndex = index - offset;

  if(dayIndex >= 0 && dayIndex < maxDay){
    days.push({
              number: dayIndex + 1,
              isPast: null,  // stuck here boolean
              isToday: null  // stuck here boolean 
     })
  }

  if(index % 7 === 6){
    week.push(days);
    console.log(week);
    days = [];

     if (dayIndex + 1 >= maxDay) {
          break;
     }
  }

 index += 1;
} while(true);
```

This works fine, the only issue Im having is to figure out if the day  is today or its in the past?

the code is here also: https://jsfiddle.net/chghb3Lq/3/

Comment: Compare it to a date created with the current date and the time set to exactly midnight. Any date less than that must not be for the same day as "today".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment has [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/), [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) and [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) functions to compare moments and as the docs says:

> If you want to limit the granularity to a unit other than milliseconds, pass the units as the second parameter.

---

There are a couple of things in your code that you can achieve in a simple way using momentjs instead of reimplementing by yourself:

- To loop from the first day of the month until the last day you can use:

  - [`startOf('month')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`endOf('month')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) as limit of the loop
  - [`add(1, 'day')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) to increment loop index
  - [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) as loop condition
- Use [`date()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/) to get date of the month (1-31)
- Use [`day()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) to get day of the week (0 => Sunday, ... 6 => Saturday); or [`weekday()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/) to get day of the week locale aware.

Using these suggestions your code could be like the following:

```js
var day = moment().startOf('month');
var endOfMonth = moment().endOf('month');

var week = [];
var month = [];

while( day.isBefore(endOfMonth) ){
  week.push({
    number: day.date(),
    isPast: moment().isAfter(day, 'day'),
    isToday: moment().isSame(day, 'day')
  });
  if( day.day() === 0 ){
    month.push(week);
    week = [];
  }
  day.add(1, 'day');
}

console.log(month);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thats awesome, thank you very much. Im new to momentjs, so appreciate this.

Answer (score 2):

Use moment methods like `isSame()` , `isBefore()`, `isSameOrBefore()` etc.

They each allow setting comparison units like `year month week day hour minute second`

See [Query Section of moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/)